# numpy average of rows with identical values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been searching for hours and cant find a good solution. I need a fast way with numpy to average a big Array of the shape (alotofrows, 3).

The numpy array looks like:

```
[[1.0,  1.0, 3.6678965], [1.0,  2.0, -3.6678965], [1.0,  3.0, 5.6678965] ....]
```

after four rows the first entry in the wow increases +1, so i have four row with the same 1st element in each row (1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3....,n,n,n,n).
How can i use numpy to average the last element every row with the same number as first element of the row ? Hopefuly without the use of loops.

> [n, b, c] : i need to check for the same n and average the c values of
>   these rows.

The Background: the array represents [ElementLabel, integrationPoint, Stressvalue] of an FEA-Sim output. The Stress of each element is calculated at 4 integration points. That is why ElementLabel is 4 times the same. I like to calculate the average of Stressvalue for each element and finally get the highest average of all elements. It is a really big amount of arrays.

Im sure its quite easy, but i cant find the solution myself :)

edit: This is my attempt:

```
for i in range(0, len(elArray)):       
    tmp_avg=(eL_iP_mIP[i][2]+eL_iP_mIP[i+1][2]+eL_iP_mIP[i+2][2]+eL_iP_mIP[i+3][2])/4
    if tmp_avg > avg:
        avg = tmp_avg
    if i+4 <= len(elArray)/4:
        i += 4
    else:
        break
```

Is there a more Pythonic way? Or where i can use numpy a bit more effective?

Comment: `(arr[:,0] + arr[:,-1])/2,0`?

Comment: your question is not clear. try to explain with some short examples and the expected results what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does `n` always come in groups of 4?  Are they always consecutive?  The layout of the `n` values will make a big difference in how easy this is.  It could be just a matter of reshaping the array and averaging, or it could require sorting and grouping first.

Comment: Ah sorry. I will explain a bit more. the first value of the array will always be 4 times the same an than increases by one. it starts with 1, 1,1, 1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,.....,n,n,n,n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution for always 4 consecutive element labels

```
a[:, -1].reshape(len(a)//4, 4).mean(axis=1).max()
```

#### Example

```
a = np.array ([[1.0, 1.0, 3.6678965], 
              [1.0, 2.0, -3.6678965],
              [1.0, 3.0, 5.6678965],
              [1.0, 2.0, -3.6678965],
              [2.0, 1.0, 13.6678965], 
              [2.0, 2.0, -3.6678965],
              [2.0, 3.0, 15.6678965],
              [2.0, 2.0, -3.6678965],
              [3.0, 1.0, 100], 
              [3.0, 2.0, 100],
              [3.0, 3.0, 100],
              [3.0, 2.0, 100]])

>>> a[:, -1].reshape(len(a)//4, 4).mean(axis=1).max()
100.0
```

### Solution for un-ordered element labels

You could use `pandas` and group by the first column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.groupby(0)[2].mean().max()
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(a)

>>> df.groupby(0)[2].mean().max())
100.0
```

Comment: Wow this looks very good! I will test it and mark thins as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot! from 230 secs to 8 secs is awesome ;)

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)